# can't understand this line of code np.mean(pred_i != y_test)

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, machine-learning

In a tutorial encountered this line of code which I am not able to understand:

```
np.mean(pred_i != y_test)
```

Complete `for` loop:

```
error_rate = []
for i in range(1,40):

    knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=i)
    knn.fit(X_train,y_train)
    pred_i = knn.predict(X_test)
    error_rate.append(np.mean(pred_i != y_test))
    print(np.mean(pred_i != y_test))
```

Answer (score 1):

`(pred_i != y_test)` will return a vector of boolean `[True, False, ...]` values.

Note that `!=` will return True for those that do not match the test values because you are interested in error.

E.g.:
`np.mean([True, True, False])` will return `0.6666666666666666`

Coming back to your question: the line you are interested in will return the fraction of those results who failed to match the test - hence your error.

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on Lajos's answer:

```py
pred_i != y_test
```

Will construct a new vector of booleans which are the result of the `!=` operation. These are automatically converted by `np.mean`. True is 1 and False is 0. You then get the mean value of the vector. I.E. 1.0 if it is all True or 0.0 if it is all False.

Answer (score 0):

`np.mean(pred_i != y_test)` will average out the value between 0-1 which will be appended to error rate. Later if you graph error rate vs k value (1-40) you will get the k value having minimum error rate. Using that K value will increase the accuracy of your model.